# Ajaxplorer file permission issue

Tags: php, ajax, pydio

I have installed ajaxplorer in local.

When i am uploading it to live server i am getting bellow error. I have already set data folder 777 permission.

```
fopen(/kcfinder/upload/cache/plugins_requires.ser): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone please help.

Comment: The error indicates the path doesn't exist - not the permissions are wrong.

Comment: i have crosschecked.. It does exist. I think i need to change some setting when i upload it live. But i don't remember it now :(

Comment: You have a folder named **kcfinder** at the root of your server?

Comment: yes. it is just a folder. I have changed upload file path in ajaxplorer.

Comment: @VibhaJ Not just a folder, a folder at the root of your server along with /var/, /etc/, /tmp/, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i have fixed this by deleting 2 cache files. If anyone is having same problem, check below 4 cases:

1) In ajaxplorer/conf/bootstrap_context.php debug AJXP_DATA_PATH value, check if it is valid or not.

2) After uploading it to live delete plugins_cache.ser & plugins_requires.ser file located under data/cache.

3) Apply 777 recursive permission to data folder.

4) Clear your browser cache and run again.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer, but not only! I've experimented the same problem. It appeared to happen with ONE user, and not with others, even on the same repository.

On the server side, go to .../data/plugins/auth.serial/[username] and delete the tmp_upload.ser file.

Also, Charles du Jeu explained that after an update, the conf files had to be updated manually. In the conf directory, you'll find the new files. Do the necessary mv.

Regards